# Tabulator - load more rows below current rows? Appending vs pagination

Tags: tabulator

Is there a way to append data vs pushing it to a new page when using pagination? I'm basically trying to have a "Load More" button at the bottom and have it add on 5 rows each time it's clicked. Is this possible with Tabulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own `paginationElement`.

I have implemented same scenario [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-cru4jt)